# Chrome Lighthouse audit always return warning 'Missing source maps for large first-party JavaScript'

Tags: google-chrome, source-maps, lighthouse, sockjs, brave

I face an issue of Chrome Lighthouse Audit.

I build a web app that loads Sock JS minified file.

The file is -> https://unpkg.com/sockjs-client@1.5.0/dist/sockjs.min.js

As you can see, there is **//# sourceMappingURL** at the end of the file.

Also, there is the source map file -> https://unpkg.com/sockjs-client@1.5.0/dist/sockjs.min.js.map

I have tried to load the SockJS minified file from the CDN and do the Lighthouse Audit several times, but it's still produce the same warning :

**Missing source maps for large first-party JavaScript**

Environment :

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Brave Browser v1.50.114

Am I missing something here or there is a bug in the Lighthouse?

Thank you.